# City cannot be converted to summable

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to use a "Summable" interface to add up the populations of the cities. I've been staring at it for an hour but still can't find my error. Please Help!

This is my tester

```
public class SummableTester extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        City cookie = new City("Coookie", 20000);
        City taco = new City("Taco", 10000);
        System.out.println(taco.getValue());
    }
}
```

City Class:

```
    public class City
    {
    private String name;
    private int population;

    public City(String name, int population)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.population;
    }
    public int add(Summable other)
    {
        return getValue() + other.getValue();
    }
}
```

Summable:

```
public interface Summable
{
    public int add(Summable other);

    public int getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implemented `Summable` interface in your `City` class, but forgot to include `implements Summable` in city class.

```
public class City implements Summable {


}
```